# what does formarray.controls in formsarray mean in angular 5?

Tags: angular

I am new to angular 5 so basically am still grasping with the concepts. Using Angular's documentation on reactive forms as an example (https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms), the following code is as given:

```
<div formArrayName="secretLairs" class="well well-lg">
<div *ngFor="let address of secretLairs.controls; let i=index" 
 [formGroupName]="i" >
    <!-- The repeated address template -->
  </div>
  </div>
```

What does secretlairs.controls mean and what is it? According to angular it means that:

The source of the repeated items is the FormArray.controls, not the FormArray itself. Each control is an address FormGroup, exactly what the previous (now repeated) template HTML expected.

Does secretlairs.controls contain any data? Can i replace this portion with lets say an object itself with data of type any and instantiated with data obtained from webapi? 
For example, instead of

```
*ngFor="let address of secretLairs.controls
```

i use

```
*ngFor="let address of addresses
```

where addresses is of type any and data obtained from database.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First, there are three type of forms - `FormControl`, `FormGroup`, and `FormArray` - all inherit from `AbstractControl`.

When you use Reactive Forms for validation and include either `formGroupName`, `formControlName`, or `formArrayName` in the component's template, you are actually declaratively defining a map between the form control tree and the root `FormGroup` model.

For example, given the following template:

```
<div [formGroup]="formGroup">
    <div formGroupName="personalInfo">
         First Name: <input type="text" formControlName="firstName"><br />
         Last Name: <input type="text" formControlName="lastName"><br />
    </div>
    <div formArrayName="cities">
        Top cities: <input *ngFor="let city of cities; index as i" type="text" [formControlName]="i">
    </div>
</div>
```

You are declaratively setting up a form map for collecting information, which will eventually produce a JSON object in a specific format. For example, given the above form model, `formGroup.value` would return:

```
{
   "personalInfo": {
        "firstName: 'John',
        "lastName: 'Smith'
    },
    "cities": [
        "New York",
        "Winnipeg",
        "Toronto"
    ]
 }
```

Once you've declared the structure of your form group in your template, you need to imperatively create the corresponding `formGroup`, `formControl`, and `formArray` in your component class.   As you setup each form, you have the opportunity to set up additional parameters:

```
  1. Initial Form Value
  2. Array of synchronous validators
  3. Array of asynchronous validators
```

This applies to any of the abstract controls.

This is what the corresponding formGroup model would look like given the above template:

```
export class AppComponent {
  firstName: string,
  lastName: string;
  cities: string[];
  @Input() formGroup: FormGroup;
  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {
    // setup initial values
    this.cities = ['New York', 'Winnipeg', 'Toronto'];
    this.firstName = 'John';
    this.lastName  = 'Smith';

    // create a formGroup that corresponds to the template
    this.formGroup = fb.group({
      firstName: [this.firstName, Validators.required],
      lastName: [this.lastName, Validators.required],
      cities: fb.array(this.cities.map(t=> fb.control(t, Validators.required)))
    })
  }
}
```

To bind to any of the form's validation flags, you can use the root `formGroup` and a path string (which supports dots) to find the particular group, control, or array.

For example:

```
<div *ngIf="formGroup.get('firstName').errors.required">First Name is Required</div>
```

Hopefully, that makes it clear.

[Edit]

Better yet, given that Reactive Forms is all about declaratively setting up a model in the template, and mapping the same model imperatively in the component class, you should consider defining a JSON model and using that instead.

For example, suppose we have a custom model `MyModel` which has a `firstName` property, `lastName` property, and a `cities` property.  The component class would look like this:

```
 export class AppComponent {
  @Input() model: MyModel;
  @Output() modelChange: EventEmitter<MyModel>;

  @Input() formGroup: FormGroup;
  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {
    this.model = new EventEmitter<MyModel>();
    // create a formGroup that corresponds to the template
    this.formGroup = fb.group({
      firstName: [this.model.firstName, Validators.required],
      lastName: [this.model.lastName, Validators.required],
      cities: fb.array(this.model.cities.map(t=> fb.control(t, Validators.required)))
    });
  }

  onSubmit() {
     if (this.formGroup.valid) {
        this.model = this.formGroup.value;
        this.modelChange.next(this.model);
     }
  }
}
```

Comment: hi there, thank you for your input. this has definitely made things much clearer on how the whole concept works. However, can you explain to me what formarray.controls specifically refer to? does it each control in the formarray.controls refer to the formgroup? can i replace this part with lets say a data model instead of controls?

Comment: The example I gave is a data model (instead of a control model)

Comment: i see, so just to point out that it is not necessary to always use the control model right? this means that if i choose to work with a data model, i will still be able to bind the user input to the form fields? ( through the formcontrol names as you mentioned in your example)

Comment: yes, that's correct.  You can bind to a regular Data model, or a Control model.

Comment: this explained the question well. Thank you. I will upvote this as correct answer