# How to assign values for multiple tds of same formcontrolname on angular

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, angular-reactive-forms

I have many input types created within table by ngFor.There are other variables created with iteration as well

**TS**

```
cars=[{id:1232,name:Toyota,bhp:500},
   {id:4321,name:Mclaren,bhp:720},
   {id:2321,name:Mercedes,bhp:470},
   {id:4321,name:Subaru,bhp:342},
   {id:5432,name:Mazda,bhp:4321}]
  CarForm= new FormGroup({
      carNumber: new FormControl(),
    });
```

**HTML**

```
<tr *ngFor = "let car of cars" >
 <td>
   <input type="text" formControlName="carNumber"">
</td>
</tr>
```

I know that Im able to pass the name value to input like this :
`CarForm.controls.carNumber.setValue(id)`.

But in this way Im not able to pass specifically row by row.
also changed my HTML like below but didnt work

```
[value]="cars(index).id"
```

How can I do that?

Comment: you should use [FormArray](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormArray) for that... [read here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50146017/what-does-formarray-controls-in-formsarray-mean-in-angular-5) for more

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A good approach as mentioned by @Argee is to use `FormArray`. The below approach uses `FormBuilder` to build the `FormGroup`

In your TS File

```
  cars=[
    {id:1232,name:'Toyota',bhp:500},
    {id:4321,name:'Mclaren',bhp:720},
    {id:2321,name:'Mercedes',bhp:470},
    {id:4321,name:'Subaru',bhp:342},
    {id:5432,name:'Mazda',bhp:4321}]
  CarForm = this.fb.group({
    cars: this.fb.array(
      this.cars.map(({id, name, bhp}) => 
        this.fb.group({
          id: [id],
          name: [name],
          bhp: [bhp]
        })
      )
    )
  })
  get carsArray(): FormArray {
    return this.CarForm.get('cars') as FormArray;
  }
  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {

  }
```

In your HTML

```
Form Value: <br>
<pre>{{CarForm.value | json }}</pre>
<form [formGroup]='CarForm'>
  <div formArrayName='cars'>
    <div *ngFor="let car of carsArray.controls; let i = index" [formGroupName]='i'><br>
      <label [attr.for]="'car-name' + i">Car {{ i + 1 }} Name </label>
      <input formControlName='name'><br>
      <label [attr.for]="'car-bhp' + i">Car {{ i + 1 }} Bhp </label>
      <input formControlName='bhp'>
      
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

[See Sample Code on Stackblitz](https://angular-ivy-q382tx.stackblitz.io)